# Execute a resource liberation action on Java's ThreadPoolExecutor's Thread death

Tags: java, multithreading, activejdbc

I have a Java ThreadPool that is initialized as follows:

```
ThreadFactory tFactory = new DatabaseWorkerThreadFactory();
final ExecutorService dbService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 5, 10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10), tFactory);
```

Then execute Runnable Task on that threadpool like this

```
executorService.execute(new RunnableDbInsertTask(netData));
```

to get those inserts to be async from the rest of my code.

As i'm using ActiveJDBC as an ActiveRecord implementation, I need each worker to have an active Connection, which I do having this code at the start of the `RunnableDbInsertTask`'s `run()` method:

```
if(!Base.hasConnection())
        Base.open(params);
```

So when the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is used, each new spawned `Thread` that gets tasks, will have a  unique connection, and will reuse it for every connection.

Now I want the thread amount to fallback to the minimum (1), as specified in the `ThreadPoolExecutor's` constructor, when there are no jobs to be done.

For this to happen correctly, I need that when a Thread is automatically finished by the `ThreadPoolExecutor` because of inactivity, it auto-finishes it's connection calling ActiveJDBC's `Base.close()` method

As a solution I tried overriding `DatabaseWorker.interrupt()` method, but that didn't worked.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  you should not rely on the executor to open and close your connections. Instead of opening direct connections to the DB, you need to use a pool of connections and open a connection from the pool. Also, at the end of your `run()` method, you must close the connection. Since these are polled connections, a real JDBC connection will simply go back to the pool instead of closing. Here is the preudo-code:

```
public void run() {        
    try {
        Base.open("myConnectionJNDIName");
        //do some real work here
    } finally {
        Base.close();//always close connection
    }
}
```

This way you have more control over thread count vs connection count.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is more appropiate